# Why jni not loading after changing package name

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Hey guys I need some help. The problem is my `jni` is not loading after changing package name. Before it was working pretty cool. I have tried to solve it but I can't. So please help me.

This is the error:

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewGlobalRef called with pending exception 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundExceptio
>       in call to NewGlobalRef
>       from java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String)

Comment: **Because you changed the package name**, in your Java code but not your JNI code, so you got a `ClassNotFoundException` from `FindClass()`, and you didn't detect that it had returned zero, so you didn't call one of the exception-handling methods, so you got this 'exception pending' error.

Answer (score 2):

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewGlobalRef called with
>   **pending exception 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'** in call to
>   NewGlobalRef from java.lang.String
>   java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader,
>   java.lang.String)

You had a pending exception when you called NewGlobalRef. When an exception occurs when executing JNI code, your app doesn't crash, but a "pending exception" is created. It is your responsibility to check for exceptions when doing JNI work which might throw an exception.

After a pending exceptions is created, only a handful of JNI methods are safe to call( mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#exception_handling)).

In your case, your app crashed because before you called `NewGlobalRef` after a pending exception was thrown. `NewGlobalRef` is not in the list of methods safe to call after an exception. However, you also see the cause of the pending exception: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Most likely this happened because you tried to do something similar:

```
cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/ndktest/SomeClass");
```

but then you changed the package name of `SomeClass` from `com.example.ndktest.SomeClass` to `com.other.package.SomeClass`. However, you probably didn't also change how you searched for the class..so you need to also update your `FindClass(...)` call to:

```
cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/other/package/SomeClass");
```

Hope this helps